# Killing a running process in an Ubuntu machine remotely from a windows machine which is in LAN

Tags: windows, process

Is it possible to kill a process running in an Ubuntu machine from a Windows(XP) machine remotely connected via LAN ?

I can kill the process in a windows machine from a remote windows machine (in LAN) by the following command,

```
taskkill /S system /U username /P password /IM process.exe
```

Is there any thing like that to kill the process running in the Linux machine ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3416/9812

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install `openssh-server` on Ubuntu and PuTTY on Windows. Then you can get a shell on your Ubuntu machine from the Windows one.

Once logged into your Ubuntu machine remotely, you can use `kill` or `pkill` or `killall` as you prefer.  I find `pkill` simplest if you just want to kill based on the process's name. For example: `pkill firefox`

If, however, you wanted to kill a specific process whose PID (process ID) you know (possibly from looking through the output of `ps -ef`), you can use `kill 1234`

You can combine kill signals with these to say how they should be killed. The default is 15, or SIGTERM (term = terminate), which is a polite request to please close now.  If a process doesn't respond to that, 9 (SIGKILL) is popular.  See `man 7 signal` for more information about signals. To use this with `kill` or `pkill` you'd simply add `-9` for example:  `kill -9 firefox`

Comment: kill -9 song: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fow7iUaKrq4

Comment: hehe I was humming that in my head as I typed

Comment: sudo apt-get install openssh-server is enough to install open ssh server  in ubuntu?

Comment: Yes.  Clicking the link I provided will automatically start up apt on your computer too.

Comment: Thanks..but now am not in Ubuntu!!! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are running an ssh daemon on your Ubuntu machine then you can login via SSH using [PuTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) from your windows machine.

Once you are logged in, you can look at the current running processes with the `ps aux` command and then use [kill or pkill](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/kill-linux-processes-easier-with-pkill/) to end the task

Note: You may need to use `sudo` with the kill commands

Answer (score 1):

If you have sshd installed on the Ubuntu box (almost always a good thing) you can connect and kill the process as normal (e.g. killall process, or similar).

On the Ubuntu box:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ssh
```

On Windows, download PuTTY:
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Open PuTTY and set it to connect to the Ubuntu box's IP address (e.g. 192.168.0.1). You should be presented with a login prompt, so provide your Ubuntu username and password.

As maco has already said, there are a variety of ways of killing processes - just take your pick of `pkill`, `killall` etc., e.g.:

```
$ killall firefox
```

Comment: Can you mention it clearly with steps?