# How to find a zombie process after reboot?

Tags: server, 10.04, process, zombie

I take a lot of time trying to connect to a Ubuntu Server, but when I finally did that I got this message:

> => There is 1 zombie process.

I reboot it immediately but now I don't know how to find a log or something about the zombie process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: [What are zombie processes?](http://askubuntu.com/q/48624/65926)

Answer (score 4):

[Zombie Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) on Wikipedia:

> On Unix and Unix-like computer operating systems, a zombie process or
>   defunct process is a process that has completed execution but still
>   has an entry in the process table. This entry is still needed to allow
>   the parent process to read its child's exit status. The term zombie
>   process derives from the common definition of zombie — an undead
>   person. In the term's metaphor, the child process has "died" but has
>   not yet been "reaped". Also, unlike normal processes, the kill command
>   has no effect on a zombie process.

...

> Zombies can be identified in the output from the Unix ps command by
>   the presence of a "Z" in the "STAT" column. Zombies that exist for
>   more than a short period of time typically indicate a bug in the
>   parent program, or just an uncommon decision to reap children.
>   If the parent program is no longer running, zombie processes
>   typically indicate a bug in the operating system. As with other leaks,
>   the presence of a few zombies is not worrisome in itself, but may
>   indicate a problem that would grow serious under heavier loads. Since
>   there is no memory allocated to zombie processes except for the
>   process table entry itself, the primary concern with many zombies is
>   not running out of memory, but rather running out of process ID
>   numbers.

Don't wory, it happens sometimes. There's no need to log this kind of event.