# How to restart banshee after crash?

Tags: sound, banshee

If banshee crashes the sound/audio system menu still shows it as available but nothing happens if I click on it. With `ps` I can see a defunct banshee process that cannot be removed. If I try to run banshee from the command line nothing happens. Restarting gdm and/or unity also has no effect. As far as I can tell there is now no way to start banshee short of rebooting which is annoying. Does anyone know how I can start banshee without closing everything down and rebooting? Perhaps there is some part of Ubuntu that controls the sound menu and I can restart that? I was hoping it was part of gdm or unity but restarting them didn't help.

ps output is:

```
john@W530$  ps -fp 20469
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
john     20469     1  0 Jul01 ?        00:04:29 [banshee] <defunct>
```

Comment: It must be a bug so I created a [ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1196828) on launchpad, although I wasn't sure what package to place it under. I think the bug is to do with whatever starts banshee.

Answer (score 0):

You can `kill <PID>` or `kill -9 <PID>` the process after determining it's PID with `ps axf |grep banshee`. After that you should be able to start the application again. As it says in your link, you should try to kill the parent process. Output looks like this for me:

`4875 ?        S      0:00          |   \_ bash /usr/bin/banshee --redirect-log --play-enqueued`

`4881 ?        Sl     0:03          |       \_ banshee /usr/lib/banshee/Banshee.exe --redirect-log --play-enqueued`

What's your output?

The **system ressources** application includes something similar to the Windows Task Manager (with just the processes) by the way.

Comment: No I can't kill a defunct process. I've tried that. See [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48624/what-are-zombie-processes)

Comment: Edited the answer.

Did you really try killing the parent process?

What's the output of your `ps`?

Comment: Parent process is root.

Comment: perhaps you can tell me what the parent process of your banshee is? Or even the whole process tree with `pstree` or something similar