# 13 times 'zenity' with status Zombie

Tags: zenity, zombie

I have 13 times *zenity* with status Zombie in my system-monitor.
Could there be any virus or what else could it be?

I have read this:
[What are zombie processes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48624/what-are-zombie-processes)
but I can't do anything with it regarding *zenity*
which is just a helper tool for programmers as far I understood and I never used that programm.

Comment: zenity is a preinstalled package, its description says "Display graphical dialog boxes from shell scripts", I don't think it is a virus. can you kill it from a terminal? Look in the system monitor for the `ID` number and then run `kill ID-number-here`, you may need sudo to kill it and that is why system monitor won't do it.

Comment: I did so but gat only 'Argument konnte nicht analysiert werden:'
(I have a german system) it is like: 
argument could not be analized: ID 4721

Comment: Try to find the parent process for zenity from this http://superuser.com/questions/137462/how-do-you-find-the-parent-process-of-a-zombie-process and, if it is not a required one, kill that.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Mark, the answer in your linked helped me to get rid of it.

`ps l` gave only two lines but `pstree -p $USER` spit out a long tree list and I could find the parent was marco (a part of d.conf in Ubuntu Mate): I had created some shortcuts in d.fonf editor.

I had terminated marco in system-monitor and all *zenity*'s were gone. Stupidly I did this while the terminal still was running and all the windows were messed up, so I had to reboot. But now all is fine and I learned something new again :)